Monotonicity and uniqueness of solution of boundary value problem
Consider a function u a solution of the following BVP: $-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-c\frac{du}{dx}=f(u)  \in (-a,a). u(-a)=1,u(a)=0$, where $f(u)=u-u^2$ so that by comparison principle $0\le u\le1$, my aim is to prove that u is decreasing and the BVP has a unique solution:
Take $h>0$ (such $h<\frac{a}{2}$), and take $u_h(x)=u(x+h)$ and define $w^h(x)=u(x)-u^h(x)$ defined in $D_h=(-a,a-h)$ and it satisfies the following boundary value problem:
$-\frac{d^2w^{h}}{dx^2}-c \frac{dw^{h}}{dx}=a(x)w^h, a(x)=\frac{f(u)-f(u^h)}{w^h}$ with $w^h(-a)=1-u(h-a)\ge 0$ and $w^h(a-h)=u(a-h)\ge 0$ so by maximum principle $w^{h}\ge 0$ now lets define:
$h_1=min(h: w^{h_0}>0, \forall h_0 \in(h,2a))$, suppose by contradition that $h_1>0$, by continuity argument $w^{h_1}\ge0 $ in $D^{h_1}$ and by maximum principle $w^{h_1-\epsilon}>0$ in $D^{h_{1}-\epsilon}$ which contradicts definition of $h_1$ there fore $h_1=0$ Which means that u is decreasing. Now to show that such solution u is unique, we suppose that v is another solution.
We argue exactly as before but with $w = v-u^h$. The same proof shows that $v\ge u^h$for all $h\ge 0$.
In particular,  $v \ge u$. Interchanging the role of u and v we conclude that $u = v$.
Is my proof right? And is there another method to prove monotonicity and uniqueness?
i dont know if it is useful but from the equation can deduce the sign of the constant c which is positive.

Are you writning $\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}u$ for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u$? Your notations do not make sense.

@geetha290krm  thanks ,yes you re right , i have edited my question , please see it

This is hard to read. Why do you divide by $w_h$ in $a(u,x)?$ if you multiply afterwards? How  do you know that $w^h(-a)\geq 0$ why is $w^h(a-h)\ge 0?$ What is $\epsilon?$

@F_M_ $w^{h}(-a)=1-u(h-a)$ and by comparaison principle we already have that $u\le 1$ thats why$w^{h}(-a)\ge 0$ for the other inequality also comparaison principle also tells us that $u\ge 0$ , for$\epsilon\ge0$small , is that clear ?, for your question is just a way to write quetion for $w^{h}$

@F_M_ do you have another method to prove that the solution is decreasing??

Your boundary conditions are $u(-a)=1,u(a)=0$ or $u(-a)=1,u(0)=0$?

@xpaul sorry for this huge mistake actually i have only $u(a)=0,u(-a)=1$

What is $0\ge u\le1$? Do you mean $0\le u\le1$?

@xpaul yes you're right.Thanks

I can't tell, is u the variable or did you mean you? Knowing that will greatly help with reading your post.

@YourLordJoyBoy u is solution of the boundary value problem

@xpaul and also how did you get that u has local maximum?

@xpaul i see that you deleted your answer , but i want to thank your proof is right ,thanks

@xpaul so your idea about uniqueness is energy functionals?

Yes. Now I don’t have enough time to complete it.

@ xpaul ,did you delete your comment ??

@RIM, my inequity has some problem.

@xpaul may be the problem is the sign because second derivative in the equation has minus sign, see again my question

Suppose $u$ is not decreasing. Since $u(-a)=1,u(a)=0$ and $u\in[0,1]$, $u$ must have a local minimum $u(x_0)$ at $x=x_0\in(0,1)$. So
$$ u'(x_0)=0,u''(x_0)\ge 0, u(x_0)\in[0,1].\tag{1}$$
Letting $x=x_0$ in the equation gives
$$ -u''(x_0)=u(x_0)-u^2(x_0). \tag{2}$$
From (1), one has
$$ u''(x_0)=u(x_0)-u^2(x_0)=0. $$
So either $u(x_0)=0$ or $u(x_0)=1$. Taking derivative of the equation at $x=x_0$ gives
$$ -u'''(x_0)-cu''(x_0)=u'(x_0)-2u(x_0)u'(x_0)$$
which implies $u'''(x_0)=0$. Using the same way, one concludes $u^{(n)}(x_0)=0$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$. So $u(x)\equiv0$ or $u(x)\equiv 1$ for $x\in[0,1]$ which is against $u(-a)=1, u(a)=0$. So (2) does not hold and hence $u(x)$ is monotonically decreasing in $[0,1]$.
Suppose there are two solutions $u_1,u_2$. Let $w=u_1-u_2$. Then $w$ satisfies
$$ -w''-cw'=w-w(u_1+u_2), w(-a)=w(a)=0. \tag{3}$$
Multiplying both sides of (3) by $w$ and integrating in $[-a,a]$, one has
$$ \int_{-a}^a|w'(x)|^2dx=\int_{-a}^a w^2(x)(1-u_1(x)-u_2(x))dt\le \int_{-a}^a w^2(x)dx. $$
By Poincare's Inequality
$$ \int_{-a}^a w^2(x)dx\le \frac{a^2}{\pi^2}\int_{-a}^a|w'(x)|^2dx $$
one has
$$ \int_{-a}^a|w'(x)|^2dx\le \frac{a^2}{\pi^2}\int_{-a}^a|w'(x)|^2dx. $$
So it $a<\pi$, one will have $w'(x)=0$ and hence $w(x)=0$ in $[-a,a]$
which is the uniqueness of the solution. For $a\ge\pi$, I don't know how to handle it so far.

The LHS is nonpositive and the RHS is nonnegative and hence both sides should be zero.

actually i dont understand why we must conclude that u is decreasing because if you assume that is increasing by your proof you'll get also a contradiction?

in your answer i'm confused because the derivative at x_0are zero but this is only at $x_0$ not for all$x$ , iam i missing something?

One point is enough since you can use Taylor expansion.

thanks  , there is a paper of Bereytski "on moving plane method and sliding method and he proves monotonicty and uniuqeness of $\Delta u=-f $ , itied to adapt this proof to my equation however i failed , can you take a look ? because  i need to prove first that there some positive h small   such u(x+h)\le u(x) and then prove that $h_1=0$ where $h_1$is the one i described in my question

I don't have Bereytski's paper.

@x paul  i  edit my question added the part where the author use this method  see above for uniqueness i suggest to use Gronwall inequality so tha  we have :$w(x)=\int_{x}^{-a}w'(x)\le \int_{a}^{-a}w'(x)\le 2a(\int_{a}^{-a}|w'|^{2}(x))^{\frac{1}{2}}\le( \int_{a}^{-a}w^2(x))^{\frac{1}{2}}$ so that $w^2(x)\le \int_{a}^{-a}w^2$and by Growall lemma we conclude

sorry for the first integral is between x and -a and please if you have any remarks please clet me know

It is not correct. The Gronwall inequality is the form $u(x)\le \int_a^xu(s)ds$.

,why? okey in the others i have to exchange -a and a but i dont see why we cant apply Gronwall lemma

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

that should work if i take this time v=1-u , then :$-v"-cv'-v^2+v=0$and define $w=v_1-v_2$ where $v_1=1-u_1$,$v_2=1-u_2$and then the positive term($c w^2$) will be in the left hand side of the inequality and Gronwall lemma will give us the unicity in this case, let me know if there is something wrong @xpaul

Write down your proof in detail.

sorry in your answer about monotoncity of thes olution i understand your proof , but just to confirm your proof is based on the fact that   a local minimum necessitates that the function increases before and after that right?@xpaul

Yes, I didn’t use advanced tools.
